# What packages are neccessary to have sound output from java applets?

Tags: 12.04, sound, java

I've got a *very minimalistic* setup of ubuntu precise, created using debootstrap. So please don't assume that any packages are installed just because they usually are. On that system, I'd like to play some sounds from a java applet. However, this always fails with the following error message:

```
javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException: Can not open line
    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftSynthesizer.open(SoftSynthesizer.java:1132)
    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftSynthesizer.open(SoftSynthesizer.java:1036)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface
        SourceDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz,
        16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian is supported.
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getLine(AudioSystem.java:476)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(AudioSystem.java:604)
    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftSynthesizer.open(SoftSynthesizer.java:1066)
    ... 35 more
```

As the messages mention a soft synthesizer, and pcm lines, I expect that the lack of some midi daemon is not the issue here. As far as I can tell, the alsa kernel modules are loaded, including `snd_hda_intel`, `snd_pcm`, `snd_seq_midi` among others. I've also included the [alsa-base](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/alsa-base) and [alsa-utils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/alsa-utils) packages in my installation. `alsa-mixer` looks good, using “HDA Intel PCH” as its default device.

What other packages, configuration settings or daemon startups does java require to make its sound output work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this myself. Using `strace` (I love this tool!), I found out that java attempts to access various alsa sound control devices. Most of them don't exist (`ENOENT`), but the first and primary one gives (`EPERM`) indicating insufficient permissions.

From there, the fix was obvious: the device in question belongs to the `audio` group, but the user running the java applet in question does not. Adding him to that group made the error message disappear.

I'm still not hearing any sound, but that might be due to some other problem, located within the applet itself.